# Internet tethering - USB to ethernet - Connection on router / not on raspberry

Tags: networking, usb

so I have a USB LTE dongle connected to my raspberry and want to share that connection to my router via ethernet. I know it would be way easier to just plug-in the dongle into the USB port of the router but that option sadly just produces crashes when downloading. Therefore I have only the option with the dongle plugged into the raspberry. Already tested huge downloads and it worked completely fine compared to the crashes with the dongle plugged into the router.

I want to share the connection of the USB dongle (usb0) to the ethernet port (eth0), which just works fine with connman. I changed only that option in the config file:

```
[...]
TetheringTechnologies = wifi,ethernet
[...]
```

The things is that I also want that the raspberry itself is connected to the internet, but that doesn't work when I'm using tethering.

I only have the option to tether the connection and the raspberry doesn't have internet anymore or to not tether and the router doesn't receive internet.

Could anybody help me so that the router and the raspberry are connected to the internet? Thanks!

Comment: What is connman? What operating system do you use?

Comment: And what config file you are talking about?

Comment: ConnMan = Connection Manager daemon; I'm talking about the connman_main.config file. I'm using LibreELEC but that part shouldn't really matter, should it?